# Executing code stored as a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

After understanding (quote), I'm curious as to how one might cause the statement to execute.  My first thought was

```
(defvar x '(+ 2 21))
`(,@x)
```

but that just evaluates to `(+ 2 21)`, or the contents of `x`.  How would one run code that was placed in a list?

Comment: I'm thinking you're asking the wrong question. What do you *really* want to do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`(eval '(+ 2 21))`

Comment: :)

Note that you can do some interesting things with backtick to control what gets evaluated by eval.

Comment: Now I'm curious... may I have an example please?

Answer (score 0):

@Christián Romo:

Backtick example: you can kinda implement apply using eval and backtick, because you can splice arguments into a form. Not going to be the most efficient thing in the world, but:

```
(eval `(and ,@(loop for x from 1 upto 4 collect `(evenp ,x))))
```

is equivalent to

```
(eval '(and (evenp 1) (evenp 2) (evenp 3) (evenp 4)))
```

Incidentally, this has the same result as the (much more efficient)

```
(every 'evenp '(1 2 3 4))
```

Hope that satisfies your curiosity!

Comment: That's interesting... I'm going to have to learn more about all these fancy little tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at funny Lisp tutorial at http://lisperati.com/. There are versions for Common Lisp and Emacs Lisp, and it demonstrates use of quasiquote and macros.